# Equivalent of Data Protection API on Linux

Tags: java, .net, windows, linux, security

Microsoft Windows 2000 and later versions expose the [Data Protection API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API) (DPAPI) that encrypts data for a per-user or per-system context. The caller does not provide a key with which to encrypt the data. Rather, the data is encrypted with a key derived from the user or system credentials.

This API is conveniently exposed in .NET via the [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class:

```
// Encrypts the data in a specified byte array and returns a byte array
// that contains the encrypted data.
public static byte[] Protect(
    byte[] userData,
    byte[] optionalEntropy,
    DataProtectionScope scope
)

// Decrypts the data in a specified byte array and returns a byte array
// that contains the decrypted data.
public static byte[] Unprotect(
    byte[] encryptedData,
    byte[] optionalEntropy,
    DataProtectionScope scope
)
```

**Is there an equivalent API on Linux?** *A bonus would be that it integrates conveniently with Java.*

What are my alternatives if there isn't one?

Answer (score 6):

There are two options for user-level key stores on Linux:

- [GnomeKeyring](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring)
- [KWallet](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kdeutils/kwallet/index.html)

This does not address the need for a system-level key store.

Comment: -1 because although these are tied to the user account, they are not Linux alternatives to DPAPI.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx

Comment: @rob, can you elaborate on why they are not "alternatives to DPAPI"? They may be different architecturally, but they achieve the same goal: allow applications to store information securely without taking care of user authentication.

Comment: @RobertChristian dpapi is also tied to the user account, by default - unless you use the localmachine flag, which is not secure in any meaningful way.

Comment: @deGoot first, these APIs are tied to graphical user environments, neither GnomeKeyring or KWallet cannot work correctly on server environment.
Second, they need a special service to run and integrate which is may or may not have an API binding on other languages than C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

DPAPI does not exist on Linux.

Windows uses a special machine-id to deviate a machine key. You can emulate this behavior by looking into "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid" reading this key and deviate your special key by using any encryption library you want.

Under Linux on the other hand this machine-id is stored in the file "/etc/machine-id". You can read it's contents and deviate your special key from it. Be aware this key may be the same when using fast deployment VMs.

Encrypt your data with this special machine-id and it cannot not be read across other machines. Read at first the machine-id (Linux or Windows) and then try to decrypt the contents of your data. On another machine the result will obviously be different and not correct.

You can code your platform independent wrapper class by using the information from above.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Here!

This documentation is so good, that I won't even bother to explain more.
Do not be discouraged with no immediate code samples on the first page. There are examples in links there. For all scenarios. DI, ASP.NET, console. Windows and Linux.

As the others before me said - AFAIK you don't have default keys for users and system in Linux. But a key is a key. You can create them and on Linux it's your (as the administrator / root) responsibility to protect the key files (meaning make them accessible only to authorized users).

The good part is you do not rely on system specific keys. You just use separate keys, your application keys.

If that is what you need - the linked API is just for you. I wish Linux had built in, default keys for users, but well... It's just one extra step for increased app-level security. Do you want one step more? Use Azure Key Vault, they have nice REST API you can use anywhere, not necessarily in Dotnet. Yes, AKV requires locally stored user password, but you can disable the access remotely, so it's a good additional security layer. If your user / machine was compromised, you just disable the secret and the target app is disabled until you provide the user with the new key. I use it in my sensitive apps a lot. Works as charm.

BTW, my minimalistic example of Linux DPAPI usage:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;

var keyDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var dataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(keyDirectory));
var protector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Test");
var password = "Secret1337";
var protectedPassword = protector.Protect(password);
Console.WriteLine($"Protected: {protectedPassword}");
var decodedPassword = protector.Unprotect(protectedPassword);
Console.WriteLine($"Decoded: {decodedPassword}");
```

Of course in real world app you won't store keys in current directory, but that's the simplest example I could think of.

Comment: Isn't the point of DPAPI that the keys are stored somewhere less vulnerable than a location the user (or hard drive thief) can directly access?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look any more (or less) advanced than PGP, or [Pretty Good Privacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy).  There are APIs available for PGP, and the one that I recall others speaking kindly of is [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/).

Here's an [example of how someone used Bouncy Castle](http://wiki.service-now.com/index.php?title=Sample_Java_BouncyCastle_Algorithm_for_Encryption).

Better APIs or solutions may be available, depending on your specific needs.

Comment: Does PGP utilize user or system credentials? It was my understanding that for PGP you need to provide your own public/private key pair.

Comment: The credentials in DPAPI is just an RSA public/private key pair, who you consider the key to belong to (system or user) is your own perception, not a function of the key.

Comment: @EdwinBuck "Because DPAPI is focused on providing protection for users and requires a password to provide this protection, it logically uses the user's logon password for protection." The issue here is that you dont have access to the users logon password, but the function gives you encryption with which the password is the key. This lets you not worry about other users (even root) gaining access to your data (in the linux case with the additional caveat that the user is not currently logged on).