# How to store passwords and sensitive data in a desktop client application (Java)?

Tags: java, security, twitter-oauth, password-protection, email

I want to make an application which will monitor user's email account for incoming emails as well as his twitter account for tweets. The user has to provide his login credentials therefore. My doubt is how and where to store this sensitive data? I don't want my application to annoy the user asking these things repeatedly.

Moreover, if I should encrypt and then store these data then how should I protect the key which I am using in my application?

Comment: The only possible answer to this is to use OS-provided encryption utilizing the user's login password (DPAPI).  You cannot magically create security from thin air.

Comment: @highcore: not really. there's plenty of aggregators out there, e.g. consider mint.com, which monitors your bank accounts for you. you have to provide your bank logins to make that work.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: @MarcB You're right. I misinterpreted the statement.

Comment: @HighCore: My application will be monitoring all that. In no way I can see the emails and tweets. So how it is invasion of privacy?

Comment: @SLaks: Can you tell me something more about OS-provided encryption/DPAPI? I have never heard about this before and am writing the application in Java.

Comment: Take example of a mail client say Thunderbird. I setup it one time by providing my mail id and password and then it automatically checks all my emails without asking for the password again. How it is done?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx http://jdpapi.sourceforge.net/ Windows only.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6032880/34397

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of encryption is to make the secrecy of a plaintext depend on the secrecy of a smaller key.

In the case, encryption alone is useless to you, since you have no way to store the key either.

Instead, you need to use some existing secret managed by a third party (using a password), and use it to derive a key.

On Windows, you can use the DPAPI, which is ultimately backed by the user's login password.
If the user forgets his password (or if it is changed from a different account), your data will be irrecoverably lost.

Note that this will not defend against code running as that user.
You need to decide what you're trying to defend against.

Comment: @stalin: If your services support it, OAuth 2 is a very good idea, but it won't help here.  You still need to keep the OAuth keys secret.  However, it greatly reduces the consequences of a leak.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it (it's no good idea but...) you may want to create encrypted storage for passwords like Firefox has for example. Users will protect passwords with master password.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is nowhere. You should never store passwords even in encrypted form. 
The "correct" way is probably simulate the behavior of similar web applications. Indeed if you login into twitter you can select check box "remember me" and twitter will not ask you for the password next time, right? How is it implemented?

Typically special token is stored on client side in cookie. The cookie is sent to server and is used for authentication. Cookie has expiration date, so it will be automatically removed when its time is over.

Unless there is better solution for desktop applications I'd suggest you to try to use this mechanism.

Comment: Take example of a mail client say Thunderbird. I setup it one time by providing my mail id and password and then it automatically checks all my emails without asking for the password again. How it is done?

Comment: @stalin It stores the passwords, and it's basically unprotected. Yes, it's encrypted on disk. And yes, it's trivially decoded, even by any random thunderbird installation, and ultimately using the, open, source code. The openness isn't really relevant, though, since the machine instructions are just there for the reading/taking.

Answer (score 0):

i think use a password that is your application wide and use that password to encrypt all other passwords and when an application say twitter is needed use that password to decrypt... further take salted-hash of master password and save it on disk.