# How do I store a symmetric key on Linux?

Tags: .net, linux, encryption, cross-platform, .net-5

I am working on a .NET 5.0 application that needs to run on Windows and Linux, and where I need to store some data (SMTP credentials). On Windows, I can encrypt these credentials using a symmetric algorith, and store the key using DPAPI via the ProtectedData class. On Linux however, there is no DPAPI and as such ProtectedData throws a PlatformNotSupportedException.

I don't necessarily need a cross-platform way to store the key - I'm fine with checking the platform at runtime and using DPAPI if supported and something else if it is not. However, how would one go about securely storing a symmetric encryption key on Linux? Preferably, I would want to use a method where only the user account that the application runs under would be able to retrieve the key, but I'm willing to look into other options.

To clarify: I'm not looking for a cryptography library, because I already have that in .NET 5. I'm looking for a secure way to store a symmetric key on Linux that only the current user can retrieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of Data Protection API on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032880/equivalent-of-data-protection-api-on-linux)

Comment: @stark My answer would be... maybe? In the answers for that question people suggest GnomeKeyring (which is not on all linux distros so can't really be relied upon), KWallet (same) and Bouncy Castle, which appears to just be a library of cryptography implementations, not something that exposes a safe way to store cryptography keys for the current user's account.

Comment: Probably write it into a file and make sure that *only* the app account can access that file/directory.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Is that possible? Surely the root account would have access too? Although I suppose at that point one would have bigger problems.

Comment: You're right. DPAPI is better in that regard.